# SQL select rows that have one specific value but not another in the same table

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table like this:

| DOC | DATE | KEY | HOUR | DEPARTAMENT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99KN001000002 | 2000-12-28 |  | 12:04:51 | DEP 1 |  |
| 99KN001000002 | 2000-12-28 |  | 12:05:35 | DEP 2 |  |
| 99KN001000002 | 2000-12-28 |  | 12:06:31 | DEP 3 |  |
| 99KN001000002 | 2000-12-28 |  | 12:07:17 | DEP 4 |  |
| 99KN001000003 | 2000-12-29 |  | 12:07:17 | DEP 1 |  |

and I would like to find out all those documents that have "DEP 1" as the only record

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in any RDBMS:

```
select DOC from table_name
where DEPARTAMENT = 'DEP 1'
and DOC not in
(select DOC from table_name where DEPARTAMENT <> 'DEP 1');
```

You can use `MINUS` or `EXCEPT` if your RDBMS supports those.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
select t.* 
from  test_tbl t 
inner join (select doc, 
            count(distinct STATUS) as nr_status
            from test_tbl 
            group by doc
            ) as t1 on t.doc=t1.doc
where t1.nr_status =1 ;
```